# How to verify whether a blinking cursor is currently inside of a text box through TestComplete

Tags: web, jscript, testcomplete

I am trying to verify that the text box gets the focus (the blinking cursor gets placed inside of it) after a certain action. I tried to use the Focused property, but it does not seem to work, or the object doesnt have this property. This is on a Web application. Here is the code

```
  reportPage = Aliases.iexplore.IESA;  
  saveWindow = reportPage.Find("ObjectIdentifier", "MainContent_saveFilterSetDialog_saveDialog", 50, true);
  saveWindowNameTextBox = saveWindow.Find("ObjectIdentifier", "*MainContent_*_sfsName", 25, true);
  if(saveWindowNameTextBox.Focused == true)
    Log.Message("The blinking cursor is inside of the name text box")
  else
    Log.Error("The blinking cursor is not inside of the name text box")
```

The logging window says "Waiting for Focused", then it fails and the log says "Unable to find the object with the specified properties"

NOTE: When I inspect this text box object in the object inspector window, "Focused" is not listed in the list of properties.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using an HTML DOM property activeElement

```
  var actualFocusedElement = Sys.Browser().Page("*BC/Report*").contentDocument.activeElement.id    
  if(aqString.Contains(actualElement, "saveDialog_tmpl_sfsName", 0, true))
    Log.Message("The blinking cursor is inside of the name text box")
  else
    Log.Error("The blinking cursor is not inside of the name text box")
```